# Is it possible to pause a recursive spider until all threads are done?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm recursively scraping multiple whole websites with Python Scrapy.
I'd like to pause my spider every x full websites **scraped**.
Unfortunately, but obviously, if I do it with an incrementer, odds are that some threads would be still on-going.
So here is my question, can we stop the requests and wait until websites that are still crawled finishes ?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you using a single spider to crawl all websites?